# executing ffmpeg using java throws Invalid argument

Tags: java, ffmpeg

I was able to execute ffmpeg in linux command line like this:

```
./ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -af 'volume=2' output.mp3
```

But when I was trying to execute the same ffmpeg executable using Java, like this:

```
String ffmpegCommand = "%s -i %s -af 'volume=2' %s";
String command = String.format(ffmpegCommand,"ffmpeg","input.mp3", "output.mp3");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

I got the following error:

```
No such filter: 'volume=2'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
```

The two commands don't seem different to me, why is the java code exec failing?

Update:
It worked after I removed the single quotes around `volume=2`. Final Java code looks like this:

```
String ffmpegCommand = "%s -i %s -af volume=2 %s";
String command = String.format(ffmpegCommand,"ffmpeg","input.mp3", "output.mp3");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Comment: Probably a difference between the first running in a shell (which probably removes the single quotes before building the internal command) and executing directly.  I would experiment with `ProcessBuilder` with each token in a separate `String[]` element and without the single quotes around `volume=2`.

Comment: It turned out that it worked after I removed the single quote around volume=2 in java code. The change was: String ffmpegCommand = "%s -i %s -af volume=2 %s";